# How to remove photos on my iPhone directly from iPhoto?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos

I'm using iPhoto '11 (version 9.4.3) on a Mac running (10.8.5).

I often need to remove a lot of poor quality photos on my iPhone from within iPhoto (ex.: 50 photos to remove). I want to manage this process from within iPhoto because I have a global vision of what I'm destroying and the risk of error is lower.

I know how to remove photos within iPhoto, and this isn't my question.

I know that tranferred photo could be located within my library and then `Photos > move to trash` will really delete the selected photos.

But I would like to avoid the time waste and the **risk of errors** due to these 2 independant operations (total loss and duplicates).

---

Is there some hidden menu entry which permit to straight forward remove a bunch of photos without transferring them?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not quite what you're asking, but Image Capture will quickly list the entire contents of the iPhone's library & allow single or multiple deletion [or indeed transfer] with shift/control select.

Comment: Thank you, you guessed right: this is not quite what I'm looking for. I'd prefer to stay with one main interface to manage my photos. One of my hidden objectives is to avoid errors, duplicates and losses.

Answer (score -1):

Once you import the photos from your iPhone to the iPhoto application, iPhoto should ask if you would like to delete those photos from your device (iPhoto).

Comment: I knew this. Please read my question :).